# Error "Too few parameters." when attempting to insert values into a database table using VBA in MS access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I've started to use access recently. I am trying to insert a few rows into the database; however, I am stuck as it is throwing an error:

> Too few parameters.

I have a table test with only one column in it named start_date I want to insert all the dates between two dates for example if I consider 1/7/2014 to 3/7/2014 I need dates as 1/7/2014,2/7/2014,3/7/2014 in my table, but I have problem inserting the code I used is as follows

```
Private Sub createRec_Click()
Dim StrSQL As String
Dim InDate As Date
Dim DatDiff As Integer
Dim db As database
InDate=Me.FromDateTxt
'here I have used a code to find out the difference between two dates that i've not written
For i = 1 To DatDiff
StrSQL = "INSERT INTO Test (Start_Date) VALUES ('" & InDate & "' );"
StrSQL = StrSQL & "SELECT 'Test'"
db.Execute StrSQL
db.close
i=i+1
next i
End Sub
```

My code throws an error in the line Db.Execuite StrSQL
as too few parameters.

Comment: A date is a decimal, Date + 1 is plus one day. DateDiff is an integer.

Comment: Please post the value of StrSql right before you run it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

since you mentioned you are quite new to access, i had to invite you to first remove the errors in the code (the incomplete for loop and the SQL statement). Otherwise, you surely need the for loop to insert dates in a certain range.

Now, please use the code below to insert the date values into your table. I have tested the code and it works. You can try it too. After that, add your for loop to suit your scenario

```
Dim StrSQL As String
Dim InDate As Date
Dim DatDiff As Integer

InDate = Me.FromDateTxt

StrSQL = "INSERT INTO Test (Start_Date) VALUES ('" & InDate & "' );"

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL StrSQL
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't run two SQL statements into one like you are doing.

You can't "execute" a select query.

db is an object and you haven't set it to anything: (e.g. set db = currentdb)

In VBA integer types can hold up to max of 32767 - I would be tempted to use Long.

You might want to be a bit more specific about the date you are inserting:

```
INSERT INTO Test (Start_Date) VALUES ('#" & format(InDate, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#' );"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove this line of code: `For i = 1 To DatDiff`. A For loop must have the word NEXT
2. Also, remove this line of code: `StrSQL = StrSQL & "SELECT 'Test'"` because its making Access look at your final SQL statement like this:

   ```
   INSERT INTO Test (Start_Date) VALUES ('" & InDate & "' );SELECT 'Test'
   ```

Notice the semicolon in the middle of the SQL statement (should always be at the end. its by the way not required. you can also omit it). also, there is no space between the semicolon and the key word SELECT

in summary:
remove those two lines of code above and your insert statement will work fine. You can the modify the code it later to suit your specific needs. And by the way, some times, you have to enclose dates in pounds signs like #

Comment: Sorry i for got to add 2 lines before end sub it is 
i=i+1
Next i

Comment: IF i remove for loop how can i enter n number of rows where n is the number of days diff between to dates.