# Insert values in PostgreSQL database from VBA MS-ACCESS

Tags: postgresql, ms-access, vba

I've seen this topic before [How to insert values into the database table using VBA in MS access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25044447/how-to-insert-values-into-the-database-table-using-vba-in-ms-access)
But it didn't solve my issue.
I'm creating a form to insert values into a table in postgresql that contains arrays [] text.
The user must select the items to add and then execute the SQL statement by clicking a button. So I first create a button and a text box to load the items to add into the array, here is the code

```
Private Sub cmdSig_Click()
 Dim registros As String
 registros = "'" & [memo] & "'" & ", "
 [resu] = registros & [resu]
End Sub
```

Then I create the button to execute the SQL INSERT INTO statement. Here is the code:

```
    Private Sub cmdPruebas_Click()
    Dim strsql As String, resultado As String, salida As String

        Dim db As Database
        dbconnect = "ODBC;DRIVER=PostgreSQL ANSI;UID=***;PWD=***;PORT=5432;SERVER=***.***.**.**;DATABASE=somedb;DSN=C:\***"
        Set db = OpenDatabase("", False, False, dbconnect)
        resultado = [resu]

        strsql = "insert into prueba_arrays (tipo_intervencion) values "
        salida = "(array[" & resultado & "]);"




        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        DoCmd.RunSQL strsql & salida
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```

If I execute the result in PostgreSQL like "Insert into sometable (array_field) values (array['value1','value2','value3']);" it works fine. But in MS-Access it says: Error 3075 'execution time' Missing operator in the query 'array['value1','value2','value3']'.
Any idea of what's happening?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DoCmd.RunSQL` runs the SQL string through the Access Database Engine. There `[..]` is interpreted as parameter, therefore the error message.

You have opened a db connection to the PostgreSQL database, but you don't use it.

It might be as simple as changing

```
DoCmd.RunSQL strsql & salida
```

to

```
db.Execute strsql & salida, dbSQLPassThrough
```

With a Pass-Through query the SQL string is passed directly to the database.

Comment: Thanks marlan and Andre, It worked fine. Thank You very much!!

Answer (score 2):

The line `DoCmd.RunSQL strsql & salida` **executes the SQL it the Access currentDb.**
Replace that line with this:

```
db.Execute strsql & salida
```

So that the SQL **gets executed from the Database object** you have opened, and connected to PostgreSQL.

Comment: Great minds think alike. :) The `dbSQLPassThrough` parameter may be necessary though.

Comment: Possibly necessary, definitely more efficient :)